# javascript error : TypeError: str is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to extract some values from a JSON array object but I get that error message.

```
var i = 0;
while (i < n) {
    $.get("counter.html").done(function (data2) {
        var $html = $("<div>").html(data2);
        var str = json.affiliates[i];
        $html.find("#coupon").html(str.affiliate_name);
        $html.find("#coupon_id").html(str.affiliate_id);
        $(".col-sm-4").append($html);
    });
    i++;
}
```

here is my json :

```
{
    "affiliates": [
        {
            "affiliate_name": "a1",
            "affiliate_id": "0"
        },
        {
            "affiliate_name": "a2",
            "affiliate_id": "0"
        },
        {
            "affiliate_name": "a3",
            "affiliate_id": "0"
        }
    ],
    "status": "success"
}
```

Comment: The problem is you're working with asynchronous code. The requests are not guaranteed to finish after each iteration.

Comment: What's `json` in this code?

Comment: What on earth is `"JSON array object"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may work:

```
var i=0;
while(i<n){
    (function(j) {
        $.get("counter.html").done(function (data2) {
            var $html = $("<div>").html(data2);
            var str = json.affiliates[j];
            $html.find("#coupon").html(str.affiliate_name);
            $html.find("#coupon_id").html(str.affiliate_id);
            $(".col-sm-4").append($html);
        });
    })(i);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a `while` loop that fires off a ton of requests with no guaranteed finishing order or even finishing - wait until they finish, increment your counter, and if needed - call again:

```
ajax(0);
function ajax(i) {
    $.get("counter.html").done(function(data2) {
        var $html = $("<div>").html(data2);
        var str = json.affiliates[i];
        $html.find("#coupon").html(str.affiliate_name);
        $html.find("#coupon_id").html(str.affiliate_id);
        $(".col-sm-4").append($html);

        if (i < n) ajax(++i)
    });
}
```

Comment: I think this will work quite well but you loose the parallel execution on the server, which is desirable on latent networks like the Internet. This may take a noticeable amount of time to complete.

Answer (score 0):

The i is not factored properly. Use a closure:

```
var i = 0;

while (i < n)
{
    (function (index) { // outer closure to factor "i"

        $.get("counter.html").done(
            function(response_data) {
                var $html = $("<div>").html(response_data);
                var str = json.affiliates[index];
                $html.find("#coupon").html(str.affiliate_name);
                $html.find("#coupon_id").html(str.affiliate_id);
                $(".col-sm-4").append($html);
            }
        );

    }(i)); // closure

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Fixed the indentation and syntax a bit, but this still doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You're right, I've inverted the closure and asynchronous code. Because the function inside `done()` is executed at a later time, the closure must be outside or it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Please specifiy what is **json** here, and according to me it would be better if you encapsulate the content of while loop in a function like

```
(function(i){
$.get("counter.html").done(function(data2) {
    var $html = $("<div>").html(data2);
    var str = json.affiliates[i];
    $html.find("#coupon").html(str.affiliate_name);
    $html.find("#coupon_id").html(str.affiliate_id);
    $(".col-sm-4").append($html);
  });
  i++;
})(i)
```

because the calls are async in nature and can produce a messed up output.